# how to use datediff properly tableau

Tags: tableau-api

basically i have the same problem with this and use this solution too https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6aS6/datediff-in-lod

so i want to count time diff between transaction for each transaction and for each users, basically my problem is just like this

[image]

same with that, ON interaction id = user id in my real data, so i want to know time different between date transaction for each users.

based on that, i made this on calculation `DATEDIFF('day',LOOKUP(MIN([Created At]),-1), MIN([Created At]))`

and here's the results

[image]

what makes me confuse is, why the first transaction of users always have time difference, instead it must be nothing because there's no time difference if you do first transaction, so how to make it not appear?

Comment: The problem may be due to filters.  Double check your table calculation by clicking the small triangle in calculated field

Answer (score 0):

Create a table calc field for First

```
FIRST()=0
```

Edit the table calc so it resets ever new user id.

[image]

Now filter for False. You can remove it from Rows, I just kept it there for demo. Your calculation will still work.

[image]

Comment: can i make the filter so if the diff is < 0 then its not appear, can i?

Comment: how to edit the filter, so if the diff day its negative, it cant appear

Comment: This filter is hiding that row, it's technically still there but hidden from view. You'll always need a first row where the diff will be negative. This just hides it.

Comment: oh i see, how about hiding the value that contains negative values (below 0)? i think i need that

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook on dropbox, gdrive?